# How to change the size and format of the text above a barplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have plotted a barplot using the following code:

ax=max_runs.sort_values(ascending=False)[:10].plot.bar(width=0.8,color='R')
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x(),       p.get_height()+0.25),color='B')

Now the values displayed over the bar graph is in float format. How do i change it into int format? And also how to reduce the size of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# Get current axis.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
ax = plt.gca()  

# Change the labels.
new_labels = [int(label) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels, fontsize=your_fontsize)
```

This is if your labels are on the x-axis, if they're on the y-axis use `ax.get_yticklabels()` and `ax.set_yticklabels()`.